# How to create a local database in visual studio?

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2013

I came from a article regarding DI at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/739232/Csharp-WPF-Dependency-Injection-Data-Demo. But First I need to create a database , I followed all the steps to load an xml, changed the server name and installed the new `SQL SERVER Tools update` yet it still says `unable to connect to the target server`.
Did I missed something?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on `View` -> `Server Explorer` -> select `Data Connection` and choose `Add Connection`:

[image]

Then select Microsoft SQL Server Database File and click on the `Continue` button:

[image]

and click on `OK`, your local database will be created.

Comment: I changed my title. So maybe could you download the file in the link and have a try?

Comment: @baozi Please ask another question with that title, this one has already been answered. Please revise your title back to the original.